# Searchable drop down for choice field in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-autocomplete-light

I have a choice field with lot's of data, I have created drop down at admin panel but I want to have a searchable drop down.

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(PublicUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['city'] = forms.ChoiceField(
       choices = CHOOSE_CITY) 

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = ItemForm

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

I have reffered [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Follow these steps

Install django autocomplete light using pip

```
pip install django-autocomplete-light
```

Then, to let Django find the static files we need by adding to `INSTALLED_APPS`, before `django.contrib.admin` and `grappelli` if present

```
'dal',
'dal_select2',
#'grappelli',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

Now You need to create an autocomplete view that will respond with filtered queryset when you search.

```
from dal import autocomplete

from your_app.models import City


class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return City.objects.none()

        qs = City.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs
```

> Note: The base view for autocomplete view should be `Select2QuerySetView`.

Now register the autocomplete view Create a [named url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) for the view

```
from your_app.views import CityAutocomplete

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^city-autocomplete/$',
        CityAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='city-autocomplete',
    ),
]
```

You can now use the autocomplete view in Item form. use `ModelSelect2` to create widget

```
from dal import autocomplete

from django import forms


class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=City.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='city-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Now you can easily use it in admin.

```
from your_app.forms import ItemForm

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = ItemForm

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

> **Note:** This will work if you have `city` field as a foreign key in the
> `Item` model.

---

If `city` is a Choice field you can [use autocompleting based on a list of Strings](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#autocompleting-based-on-a-list-of-strings)

Create a listview using `Select2ListView` and override `get_list` method

```
class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2ListView):
    def get_list(self):
        # return all cities name here, it will be auto filtered by super class
        return ['Pune', 'Patna', 'Mumbai', 'Delhi', ...]
```

Register URL as above, now modify your model form  and use `Select2ListChoiceField`

```
def get_choice_list():
    # all cites to used as chice list
    return ['Pune', 'Patna', 'Mumbai', 'Delhi', ...]


class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = autocomplete.Select2ListChoiceField(
        choice_list=get_choice_list,
        widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(url='city-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Add this form to ModelAdmin as we did in above example.

Comment: I have to use `ChoiceField` not `ModelChoiceField` . I have tried 
            self.fields['slack_channel'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices = get_my_choices(),
            widget=autocomplete.Select2(url='choose_channel')
            )
but i am not getting 'q' from admin

Comment: if `city` is a  field in your Item model you can user `ModelChoiceField` while creating  form

Comment: Also use `ModelSelect2 ` not `Select2 ` in widget

Comment: @Satendra you have an error in your code - there should be no invokation of "is_authenticated" in the view, it should just be - if not self.request.user.is_authenticated - otherwise you will gett "bool object is not callable"

Comment: @Jhnsbrst Yes exactly. Thanks for the heads up. updated the answer.